# android Method setOnPreparedListener must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am loading video from async task and get this error

> Method setOnPreparedListener must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker.

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.start();
                duration = videoView.getDuration();
            }
        });

        do {

            current = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                    + current);

            if (sync.isCancelled())
                break;

        }

        while (current != duration || current == 0);

        return null;
    }
```

What to do?

Comment: You have your answer, call from main thread.

Comment: @Spartan But how?

Comment: You should do it in `onPreExecute`

Comment: outside of Async task

Comment: @ Veneet Reddy Please give some example

Answer (score 0):

Move it to onPreExecute(Executed on the UI thread). Inside your `AsyncTask` add this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.start();
                duration = videoView.getDuration();
            }
        });

    }
```